# What does mongoose.Document and bitwise AND mean in this context?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

In a sample Node.js/TypeScript project starter template, I see the following code segment in a data model file:

```
export type UserModel = mongoose.Document & {
  email: string,
  password: string,
  ...
}
```

What does the `mongoose.Document &` construct mean and do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you denote an [intersection type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) in TypeScript, and it has nothing to do with the bitwise operation in this context.

An intersection type just means the new type must adhere to both of the component types. So in this case, the `UserModel` type has all the properties of a `mongoose.Document` as well as the additional ones in the second type (`email`, `password`).